# Any way to shorten this if statement? PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to keep my code nice and elegant. Any way to make this if statement shorter?

```
if(strlen($cname) > 100) {

} 
if(strlen($cowner) > 100) {

} 
if(strlen($cemail) > 200) {

} 
if(strlen($cpassword) > 100) {

}
```

I can't do this because I want to print out a specific message for each if statement:

```
if(strlen($cname) > 100 || strlen($cowner) > 100 || strlen($cemail) > 200 || strlen($cpassword) > 100) {
  // I want to print out a message like email is too long not just one of these strings is too long
}
```

Comment: At what points are you wanting to output a message?

Comment: you could loop an array of the variables to check, but i dont think that's really any better

Comment: You won't want to use `elseif` if your goal is to print an error message for any of these conditions is true. Your current structure will only show the first error that comes up. There are a number of ways you can validate these variables, depending on how they are getting assigned.

Comment: I think you've got the most elegant solution for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: If this is coming from a POST, why not put the "limit" on the front-end as with `maxlength`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, I think you've got the most elegant solution for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please consider adding a proper answer. This statement could probably go well in the comments section.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop to reduce the number of lines. Here is an optimized solution even when you have more 10 fields to check:

**Declare an array of fields and loop through it**

```
$fields = array("cname" => 100, "cowner" => 100, "cemail" => 200, "cpassword" => 100); // key as field name and value as maximum limit - new values can be added here.

foreach($fields as $field => $length) {
   if(strlen(${$field}) > $length) {
       die("$field field can only contain $length characters"); 
   }
}
```

**Edit:** You can also keep all errors in an array and then print all the errors on your page.

```
$errors = array();
foreach($fields as $field => $length) {
   if(strlen(${$field}) > $length) {
        $errors[] = "$field field can only contain $length characters"; 
   }
}
print_r($errors);
```

Answer (score 0):

You already using an optimized code. But you can optimize it little bit more for showing error message. Like below:

```
$invalidFieldName = '';
$invalidFieldLength = 100;
if (strlen($cname) > 100) {
    $invalidFieldName = 'CNAME';
} elseif (strlen($cowner) > 100) {
    $invalidFieldName = 'COWNER';
} elseif (strlen($cemail) > 200) {
    $invalidFieldName = 'CEMAIL';
    $invalidFieldLength = 200;   
} elseif (strlen($cpassword) > 100) {
    $invalidFieldName = 'CPASSWORD';
}

if ($invalidFieldName != '') {    
    echo $invalidFieldName." should be greater than ".$invalidFieldLength;
}
```

I am not really sure if it will help you but I hope it will help you.